# How to receive OAW mail in Outlook?

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server, webmail

We have a Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 and we have Outlook Web Access to access the mail. It connects through a HTTPS connection.

Is there a way to receive the mail in Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you connect your Outlook to the Exchange Server, you can read the mails directly from Outlook.